# How to use web browser object in background worker in C#

Tags: c#, browser, backgroundworker

I have problem with code below. Can some one tell why it doesn't work in BackgroundWorker and how can i solve this problem

```
  string address = "My URL";
            webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address));
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            } while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!!

You better open a new thread and instruct the WebBrowser from there

`Application.DoEvents()` is kinda [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/245495).

Here is how you can start

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    yourWebBrowser.Navigate("http://Google.com");
});

t.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
t.Start();
```

To get notified that the page has been loaded you can subscribe to the DocumentCompleted event as so:

```
yourWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;

void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: No because backgroundWorker has an ApartmentState of `MTA` instead of `STA` that webbrowser needs

Comment: @arash Did this worked out? Consider accepting this answer if it resolves your issue